# Divide by zero error encountered in my Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whenever I run this query:

```
 SELECT
     Call_DT, 
     CAST(Talk_Sec_Count + Alloc_Sec_Count AS DECIMAL(16, 4)) AS Talk,
     CAST(CT_Count * 1.0 - NP_Count  / CT_Count * 1.0 AS DECIMAL(16, 4)) AS Quality,
     Pymt_Rtn_Rt AS Utilization,
     Agent_UID
 FROM 
     [TableName] 
 WHERE
     [Call_Date]  <= 13
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
> Divide by zero error encountered.

Question: what do I need to do to insert 'ZERO' in the table to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NULLIF()`:

```
 CAST(CT_Count * 1.0 - NP_Count  / NULLIF(CT_Count * 1.0, 0) AS DECIMAL(16, 4)) AS Quality,
```

This returns `NULL` if the denominator is `0` -- preventing the error.

Comment: If CT_Count is null, won't `NULLIF(CT_Count * 1.0, 0)` return 0?  Which would still result in a divide by 0?

Comment: It's `NULLIF` not `ISNULL`, @Andrew . *If* first expression returns the second, then `NULL` is returned, otherwise the value of the expression is. If the value of the first expression is `NULL`, then (in this example) that *doesn't* equal `0` and so `NULL` is returned.

Comment: @Larnu - you are absolutely correct. `IS NULL` <> `NULLIF`, despite what my brain thinks...

Comment: `IS NULL` is also another thing entirely to `ISNULL` @Andrew ;)